# Python Pandas - Deal with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I want to deal with duplicates in a pandas df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,1],'B':[2,2,1,2,1],'C':[2,2,1,1,1],'D':['a','c','a','c','c']})
df
```

I want to keep only rows with unique values of A, B, C an create binary columns D_a and D_c, so the results will be something like this without doing super slow loops on each row..

```
result= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2],'B':[2,1,2],'C':[2,1,1],'D_a':[1,1,0],'D_c':[1,1,1]})
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: How would you like to construct `D_a` and `D_c` to get from a single five-element list to two three-element lists?

Comment: so what is the rule for creating D_a and D_c?  I understand the rationale in wanting to remove duplicates, but what do you hope to do with D_a and D_c?  Sounds like there may be a better way to achieve the end goal.

Comment: If one of our answers helped, please vote on, and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `get_dummies` + `sum` -

```
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])\
       .D.str.get_dummies()\
       .sum(level=[0, 1, 2])\
       .add_prefix('D_')\
       .reset_index()

df

   A  B  C  D_a  D_c
0  1  1  1    1    1
1  1  2  2    1    1
2  2  2  1    0    1
```

Comment: @RoadRunner Ah well! It happens. Voters are fickle beasts. Best not to let it get under your skin. Just enjoy your time here, share your knowledge, and learn from others. Cheers :-)

Comment: Yeah I agree. Always impressed with your answers btw.Top notch python I must say.

Comment: @RoadRunner Thank you, I appreciate that. I still have a long way to go though. But I'd like to think I'm getting there. The thing is to always keep an open mind and be receptive to feedback. There's more to reputation than the number under your profile. :-)

Comment: @toumz Cheers, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('D_')
         .clip_upper(1)
         .reset_index()  
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df1)
   A  B  C  D_a  D_c
0  1  1  1    1    1
1  1  2  2    1    1
2  2  2  1    0    1
```

Comment: Impressive indeed.

Comment: I'll add that the important subtlety here is `clip_upper`. Without this duplicates are not removed. This is clearer with `pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,1,1],'B':[2,2,1,2,1,1],'C':[2,2,1,1,1,1],'D':['a','c','a','c','c','c']})` (simply repeated last row). Very nice!

Comment: @josh - Thank you very much, nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
df.loc[df['D']=='a', 'D_a'] = 1
df.loc[df['D']=='c', 'D_c'] = 1
```

This will put a 1 in a new column where every an "a" or "c" appears.

```
    A   B   C   D   D_a  D_c
0   1   2   2   a   1.0  NaN
1   1   2   2   c   NaN  1.0
2   1   1   1   a   1.0  NaN
3   2   2   1   c   NaN  1.0
4   1   1   1   c   NaN  1.0
```

but then you have to replace the NaN with a 0.

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Next you only have to select the columns you need and then drop the duplicates.

```
df = df[["A","B","C", "D_a", "D_c"]].drop_duplicates()
```

Hope this is the solution you were looking for.